# beautifulsoup4 installation & import using python3 on mac

Tags: python, macos, installation, beautifulsoup

I am going crazy about the installation of beautifulsoup4 on my macbook on which I have Python 3.x installed.

I managed to install beautifulsoup by typing "python3 setup.py install" in the console. After going through some code the console tells me

```
Installed /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.4.0-py3.5.egg
Processing dependencies for beautifulsoup4==4.4.0
Finished processing dependencies for beautifulsoup4==4.4.0
Patriks-MacBook-Pro:beautifulsoup4-4.4.0 Patrik$
```

But when I run "import bs4" in Python, it keeps telling me

```
import bs4
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2205, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2190, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2132, in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1908, in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1884, in _get_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1865, in _legacy_get_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 864, in spec_from_loader
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 905, in spec_from_file_location
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.4.0-py3.5.egg/bs4/__init__.py", line 48
    'You are trying to run the Python 2 version of Beautiful Soup under Python 3. This will not work.'<>'You need to convert the code, either by installing it (`python setup.py install`) or by running 2to3 (`2to3 -w bs4`).'
                                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

but as far as I can see I installed the 4..4.0 version of beautifulsoup4.

There seem to be a lot of people how are seeking for a short but clear noobie-tutorial how to install bs4 in Python 3.x on a Mac with OS 10.x

Hopefully someone can help us out...

Comment: pip3 install BeautifulSoup ?

Comment: As the error says run this command: 2to3 -w bs4. Install 2to3 if you don't have it.This will convert the beautifulSoup compatible from python version 2.* to 3.*. I have tested it and it's working for me.

Comment: Mir alias is correct. How come that I have not found this anywhere before??? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Actually the pip3 install BeautifulSoup produces a strange error for me:

```
Collecting BeautifulSoup
  Downloading BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-prl0vx3e/BeautifulSoup/setup.py", line 22
        print "Unit tests have failed!"
                                      ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

But sudo pip3 install BeautifulSoup4 works!